# Parse html source code into xml tree

Tags: python, html, xml, html-parsing

I know there's many ways to do this using 3rd party libraries such as `resources`, `pyparsing`, `selenium`, etc. but I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to do it without any 3rd party modules.

Basically what I want to do is take the HTML code from the page source of a webpage and parse it into xml format (probably using `xml.etree.ElementTree`). I've tried this:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = urllib.request.urlopen(website)
tree = ET.fromstring(data.read)
```

However when I do this I either get mismatched tags or unknown symbol for UTF-8 encoding, which the page source is definitely in. I was under the assumption that a functioning html page wouldn't have mismatched tags so I'm thinking there's something I'm missing.

And the whole reason I don't want to use a 3rd party library is because I need to grab a small set of information and don't think it's enough to justify using another module.

Comment: Save the page into a file and pass it into a html validator, so you can see whether there are mismatched tags

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is that valid HTML is not necessarily valid XML.  XHTML was an attempt to change this but has largely been ignored.

Comment: There are definitely some mismatched tags. Thanks for that suggestion. Also, this page is xhtml. I think I may have to write a sub parser to grab the information I need and then I might be able to parse it into a tree structure